# Adding spaces to an apex class definition

Tags: apex, json

So I'm working with an endpoint that for whatever reason, has a spacespace for one of the *required* parameters.

```json
{
    "parameterOne": {
        "Ref Number": "abc123456", //required
        "notRequired": "",
        "notRequired":""
    },
    "parameterTwo": {
        "activeOnly": "false",
        "page": 1
    }
}
```

I've tried hitting this ep with serialized json and a blob but both times, I get an error saying I need an object. Since I can't just create an object literal, pretty sure I need to create a new class and instantiate a new object. The only issue is, I don't know how to get around the space between Ref and Number in ParameterOne.

```java
    public Parameter1 parameter1;
    public Parameter2 parameter2;

    public class Parameter2 {
        public string activeOnly;
        public integer page;
    }

    public class Parameter1 {
        public string Ref Number;
        public string notRequired;
        public string notRequired2;
    }
```

When I try to deploy this class to my sandbox, I'm hit with an error. It doesn't know what Ref is, which is understandable.

Can anyone think of a way to get around this?

edit: I konw the paramters are mismatched. In my actual code, they're all matching and hunky dory.

Comment: In your deserialization class, the space between `Ref` and `Number` in `Parameter1` strikes me as problematic. If you can't alter the JSON string (either on the server side or the client/Salesforce side), then you'll need to use `JSON.deserializeUntyped()` here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After re-reading your question, the solution here is indeed either to modify the JSON before you deserialize it, or deserialize untyped.

Using `JSON.deserailizedUntyped()` would look like

```java
// Using a Map<String, Object> because your JSON starts with an "Object".
// If it were instead a List, you'd use a List<Object> instead
Map<String, Object> deserializeResult = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(myJsonString);
```

Deserializing untyped involves a lot more typecasting. You need to typecast the result of the deserialization (though you'd also need to do that with `JSON.deserialize()`), but each level that you traverse in an untyped deserialization also needs to be typecast. So to get at `ref number`, you'd need to

```java
Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserialize(myJsonString);

Map<String, Object> firstLevel = (Map<String, Object>)result.get('parameterOne');

String refNumber = (String)firstLevel.get('Ref Number');
```

Note that because you're deserializing to a `Map<String, Object>`, the string "key" will be case-sensitive (whereas the rest of Apex is generally case-insensitive).